# Machine interfacing using Cross-over network cable to my computer

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am working with a medical equipment. It is capable to connect to the internet using cross-over cable. I am making a LAN connection between machine and computer using cross-over cable. And a server application is running on my computer to receive message from my machine. But problem is a desktop computer is connecting and receiving message very well. But laptop does not works. Both desktop and laptop has same internet setting. Why laptop not working???

Comment: What OS are you using? Can you clarify the subnets? Also I am not sure [su] is the correct place for repairing medical equipment, I would suggest contacting the vendor.

Comment: Related: [Do I need a cross-over cable?](https://superuser.com/q/186460)